# How does Mathematica obtain this result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

```
FullSimplify[
 Sqrt[2 π] InverseFourierTransform[1/(x^2 - a^2), x, p], 
 Element[a, Reals]]
```

Gives the output

```
-((π Sign[p] Sin[a p])/a)
```

But

$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{e^{-i k x}}{x^2-a^2} \, dx$ is not a defined integration. Mathematica also returns undefined as answer if you compute it.

So, I am trying to understand how does Mathematica calculates that Fourier transform of the non-integrable function.

Comment: The FT is defined for many cases where that integral is not.

Comment: In particular, the principal value of the integral equals the FT.

Comment: For me works fine.Try: `Integrate[Exp[- I p x]/(x^2 - a^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True, 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals, p \[Element] Reals}]`.MMA **12.2.0** give me: `Piecewise[{{-((Pi*Sin[a*p])/a), p >= 0}}, (Pi*Sin[a*p])/a]`